# CakePHP redirection issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I built a site with CakePHP and its working just fine. Now I've place another `wordpress` built blog within `app/webroot` folder.

Suppose:

`example.com` (cakephp site)

and need `example.com/myblog`

I placed all my files to `app/webroot/myblog`. but when i hit the url second it redirects me to

`example.com/app/webroot/myblog` with `404 NOT FOUND` Error.

Now what can I do to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put this in the main root/.htaccess
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your htaccess : (be sure that this comes before any other rewrite rules)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myblog(/.*)?$ - [L]
```

Comment: no the htaccess in your root public folder ( where `http://example.com/` point to )

Comment: That would not work. I mean placing the .htaccess in the DocumentRoot of the hosting except you are placing your blog folder there, too. Get rid of the first two lines and put the last one in the .htaccess file in your app/webroot/. That should work fine. Maybe you have to write a RewriteBase entry in the app/webroot/myblog/.htacces file which contains "/app/webroot/" as value, but I am not 100% sure about that.